# Is it possible to share resources between single page applications (SPAs) running in different tabs in the same browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend, single-page-application, mean-stack

Is it possible to share resources (e.g. memory) between single page applications (SPAs) running in different tabs in the same browser?

Example

1. A user opens up my SPA in a tab and some data is downloaded to the client
2. The user then opens my SPA in a new tab. This could be with `Open link in new tab` or by entering in the URL
3. The SPA in the new tab needs the same data as was downloaded in step 1.

Is it possible to access the local data, instead of downloading it again?
If this is possible I would like pointers on how to do it with a MEAN stack.

Comment: If you open the same app in two distinct browser tab you have two separated instances of the same app which can't communicate each other. You can use some kind of localStorage, sessionStorage or cookie caching

Comment: Ok - are they really the only ways? Which one is best practice?

Comment: It depends on your requirements... cookies has a builtin to handle with expiration while localStorae is almost permanent; if you need to share large amount of data probably it's better localStorage... it depends on may factors, there is not a better answer for all the cases

Comment: Thank you. That is at least something to get me started :)